# DataFrame performance warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I am getting performance warning from Pandas

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:1471: 
PerformanceWarning: 
your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot
map directly to c-types [inferred_type->mixed-integer,key->block0_values] [items->['int', 'str']]
```

I've read several issues on github and questions here, and all of them say this is because I mix types in one column, but I definetely not. The simple example is follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['int', 'str'])
df = df.append({ 'int': 0, 'str': '0'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({ 'int': 1, 'str': '1'}, ignore_index=True)
for _, row in df.iterrows():
   print(type(row['int']), type(row['str']))

# <class 'int'> <class 'str'>
# <class 'int'> <class 'str'>

# however
df.dtypes
# int    object
# str    object
# dtype: object

# the following causes the warning
df.to_hdf('table.h5', 'table')
```

What can this be about and what can I do?

Comment: Have you tried converting numeric columns to numeric? For example, `df[col] = df[col].astype(int)` ?

Comment: @jpp Wow! That's it! Thank you! Am I just a little inexperienced not to know it is needed or is it a trick?

Comment: see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your dataframe series to numeric types, where appropriate.

There are 2 main ways to achieve this for integers:

```
# Method 1
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int)

# Method 2
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], downcast='integer')
```

This ensures data types are appropriately mapped to C-types, and thus enables data to be stored in HDF5 format (which PyTables uses) without the need for pickling.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @jpp's answer, I traced this issue in my own data to the default use of `int64` and `float64` data types when loading a large CSV into a pandas data frame.

Resolved with:

```py
for c in df.columns[df.dtypes=='float64'].values:
        df[c] = df[c].astype('float')
    
    for c in df.columns[df.dtypes=='int64'].values:
        df[c] = df[c].astype('int')
```

Can now export to HDF without warnings. You could, of course, automate this, but for my purposes this was 'good enough'.